# Can't set to Fast PWM OCRA mode

Tags: avr, atmega, c, timer, interrupts

Trying to have Fast PWM mode when `TOP == ORCA`.

[image]

Works fine with `OCA` toggle (measuring correct frequency), but doesn't work in non-inverting mode.

[image]

```
cli();

// Fast PWM Mode 
TCCR2A = 0;
TCCR2A |= _BV(WGM20) | _BV(WGM21) | _BV(COM2A0) | _BV(COM2A1); // Inverting mode fails
//TCCR2A |= _BV(WGM20) | _BV(WGM21) | _BV(COM2A1); // Non-Inverting mode fails
//TCCR2A |= _BV(WGM20) | _BV(WGM21) | _BV(COM2A0); // Toggle mode OK

// Prescaler set to 1024 (p.162)
TCCR2B = 0;
TCCR2B |= _BV(CS20) | _BV(CS21) | _BV(CS22) | _BV(WGM22);

// Enable interrupt on counter match
TIMSK2 |= _BV(OCIE2A);

OCR2A = 127;

sei();
```

Update with more information:

MCU=Atmega328. In non-inverting mode I just got steady 1 on output and inverting mode gives logical 0. I was expecting to see the frequency

$$F = 16*10^6 / (1024 * 127) = 123Hz$$

Comment: What happens exactly when it "doesn't work"? What MCU is it? And what was the expected behavior as per you? The question needs a bit of clarity please.

Comment: Sorry, updated with clarifications.

Comment: Worth to mention that Fast PWM (0xFF) mode works fine(WGM22=0).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will answer myself. OC2A pin is not generating frequency, because OCR2A is busy holding TOP value. It can hold either TOP value or output compare value. So I should use OCR2B.

Answer (score 0):

To solve your controller problem, try this:

I just used the source code example of

http://www.electronicsplanet.ch/mikrocontroller/avrcodesammlung/atmega16timer0fastpwm.htm

and it worked. But thanks to your explanations, I understand why it works ;-)